# Dask drop duplicates memory errors split_out

Tags: memory-management, duplicates, out-of-memory, dask, dask-distributed

I have a big parquet dask dataframe (40 GB) with 600 partitions and need to drop_duplicates with dask.

I noticed that a simple drop_duplicates always results in 1 partition, so I included "split_out".

The parquet file with partitions was created from csvs, each of which were already deduped.

When I run it I always get memory errors workers exceeding 95% memory.

When monitoring the dashboard, I also noticed the workers only fill up their RAM space to like 70% max, thus I do not understand why I run into memory issues.

```
dataframe.map_partitions(lambda d: d.drop_duplicates('index'))
```

....will not work as it only dedups in each partition but not across.

Any idea how I can calculate the optimal partition size so drop_duplicates will run on my 2 workers with 25GB Ram each?

```
client = Client(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=2, memory_limit='25000M',diagnostics_port=5001)
b=dd.read_parquet('output/geodata_bodenRaw.parq')
npart = int(b.npartitions)
print('npartitions are: ',npart)
b=b.drop_duplicates(subset='index',split_out=npart)
b=b.map_partitions(lambda d: d.set_index('index'))
b.to_parquet('output/geodata_boden.parq', write_index=True )
```

Comment: @mdurant: could you help?

Comment: user670186 you can't reference user that are not already commenting this question. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175009/how-can-i-reference-another-user-in-an-answer)

Comment: Then `map_partition` is designed to perform independently in every partition so the behaviour you are having is the normal one.

Answer (score 2):

> When monitoring the dashboard, I also noticed the workers only fill up their RAM space to like 70% max, thus I do not understand why I run into memory issues.

Dask starts to get concerned around this level, and starts writing data to disk.  It needs to keep some free memory for your functions to run.  See here for information on how to change these policies: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management

In general uniqueness or dropping duplicates is an expensive operation to run in parallel, particularly for high-cardinality datasets.  Using the split_out parameter is a good idea.  In your situation I would play more with that.